# Cannot get image to display in picturebox when trying to load if from the DB

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from mainDB where Surname = @surname", myConnection)


    cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text


    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim table As New DataTable()


    adapter.Fill(table)


    TextBox4.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
    TextBox5.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
    TextBox6.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
    TextBox7.Text = table.Rows(0)(9).ToString()
    TextBox8.Text = table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
    TextBox9.Text = table.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
    RichTextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)(6).ToString()
    RichTextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(10).ToString()
    RichTextBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(7).ToString()
    TextBox10.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(str)

    myConnection.Close()
```

I've googled for hours trying to make this work and I'm pretty sure it's something simple. The image is stored on the DB as a string (using the path)

Is my syntax correct?

this is my method of uploading the image to the DB:

```
    Private Sub newImgbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles newImgbtn.Click

    Try
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Jpeg|*.jpg"
        strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(strFileName)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Upload Cancelled")

    End Try
```

Then send it to the DB via a string:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strFileName
```

Comment: Is your code complete? What is that _str_ variable suddenly appeared in your code and used as  a Stream instance?

Comment: What exactly did  you save to the DB?  Bytes? Filename?  Probably not a stream - SQL Server can do that but not access.  You dont need an Adapter and DataTable for that - a DbReader would have been enough

Comment: @Plutonix this is what I used to upload the path to the DB:      cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strFileName

Comment: @Steve I forgot to remove that as it was part of something else that I tried prior to making this post which didn't work

Comment: if you saved the filename, you need to open it and create an image from it provided it *is* and image: `Image.FromFile()` note that since you create the image you are responsible for disposing of it later or your app will leak

Comment: @IanProbets please [edit] your question with the actual code and explain also the part  where you save the 'image' (it seems that you just save a string representing a file name)

Comment: Okay i get you, so do I now need to create a string to do that? also ref the leakage. would I be right in thinking that I need to use Image.Dispose?@Plutonix

Comment: @Steve sorry, see edited post.

Comment: You probably want to revise that image storage system.  a) if this is like a student DB (`mainDB` is a terrble table name, BTW), the images could be coming in from flash drives which wont be there later or b) just get replaced; c) they could all be named "me.jpg".  A better way is to copy the file to a folder somewhere and rename it.  I save just the file name, and append the folder specified by a setting so it it easy to move the image archive or entire folder.  I prepend the record ID: save the record, get the Id, then rename the file and update the record

Comment: I would actually use a format like `1087_Ziggy J Walters.jpg` Rename the file to include the ID and the name.  You can also use a GUID if you want to do it in one step, I like the dual linkage though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

First off, I created a string:

```
strFileName = table.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
```

then told the picture box to load the string:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(strFileName)
```

And it now works.

Answer (score 0):

picturebox1.image=image.fromFile(pathhere)